# What does this そういうことよ mean?

Tags: meaning, spoken-language

> Woman 1「遠慮しておくわ。私はそういうときは、時間をかけてゆっくりとしたい方だから」
>
> そう微笑むと、彩葉さんは席を立った。
>
> Woman 1「良ければあなたも、私の金魚を見に来てね。大丈夫。みんながみんな高額なわけではないわ」
>
> Guy 1「……約束は難しいですけど、機会があれば」
>
> Woman 1「ええ。それでは、失礼いたします」
>
> 彩葉さんは、言葉は柔らかいもののどんな言葉にも惑わされず、キッパリと振り切って帰っていった。
>   少なくともルカを相手にするのなら、あのくらい毅然とした態度が必要なんだろうな……。
>
> Woman 2「ま、そういう趣味でないことはわかっていたけどね」
>
> ルカも彩葉を見送りながら、特に残念そうな様子もない。
>   おそらく、これも初めてのやりとりじゃなかったんだろう。
>
> Woman 2「さて、**そういうことよ**、クズ」
>
> Woman 2「まずは、そのケースの中を確認するわ。出しなさい」

Context: Woman 1 had come over to deliver some Goldfish to Woman 2, and Guy 1 had came to deliver some clothes she had ordered. Woman 2 invites Woman 1 to "join them" but she declines and then we get the rest of the scene that follows. My problem lies with what そいうこと is referring to in this context, as these kind of phrases are highly dependent on context. The only thing I can think of is that it refers to the conversation as a whole and is used to end their conversation about that after woman 2 left, and to move onto her clothes and other things, but this doesn't quite sit right with me. そういうことってどういうこと？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そういうこと = 彩葉さんが、誘いを断って帰っていったという結果・状況。

Answer (score 0):

さて、そういうことよ = "Well, that's it".

Probably, she refers to her previous statement そういう趣味でないことはわかっていたけどね  by "it".